# Check if any field has empty value in a table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, xquery

I recently, approx 2 months ago, needed to check for any field in a table that has NULL value.

I am now onto another task but this time i need to check if any field in a table has an Empty String value.

Starting Query:

```
;With xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns)
SELECT *
FROM [Schema].[Table] act
where (
    select act.*
    for xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type
).exist('//*/@ns:nil') = 1
```

I know i need to change `@ns:nil` but as i am uneducated on TSql's XQuery implementation, i need someone to help me with this initial query.  As well, where i should go outside of MSDN to get read up on usage and functionality.

Update #1:

```
;With xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns)
Select *
from Schema.Table act
where (
    select act.*
    for xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type
).value('(//row/*)[1]', 'varchar(max)') = ''
```

Tried this but evidently one of the fields contains character `0x001C` and so requires a conversion to binary, varbinary, or image and then use `BINARY BASE64` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the XML and check for node values that are empty. Simpler than checking for null and as stated in comment, only (n)varchar produces an empty string as a node value.

```
select *
from T
where (
      select T.*
      for xml path(''), type
      ).exist('*/text()[. = ""]') = 1
```

Comment: The columns i need to search through are VarChar fields.  And the fact is that XQuery would be alot faster as some tables only have 7 fields and others have well over 50 fields.  As such i need to "relatively" easily iterate through the various tables to then find out which ones have Empty values in them so i know which to convert to NULL.

Comment: Do you mean that every column in the table is a varchar column or do you only want to check the varchar columns? And I don't think the XQuery version is faster. Faster to type yes. Not faster to execute. Perhaps you should look at creating the where clause dynamically so your code can be reused for multiple tables?

Comment: preferably check only the varchar fields.  But wouldn't `empty()` return NULL instead of 0 or 1 if the value type was not string compliant?

Comment: For xml path turns the row to XML and from there every column is a string I the XML. There is no xsd around to type the nodes in the XML.

Comment: I will have a go at this using XQuery later. It might just work.

Comment: The only problem with this is that if any of the text fields have crazy characters this blows up, but this also alerted me of invalid characters.  So the error was also a help in identification.

Comment: @GoldBishop If by crazy you mean control characters under 32 except for 9 10 and 13 then you are correct. Those are not part of XML 1.0 which is what SQL Server supports. There might be others in some high Unicode but I don't remember. It is in the spec for XML.

Comment: Yeah most were Hexed under 32 when SQL reported the error.  Again, it works awesome and helped identify invalid characters making it through the Data Transform process.